# Debian package to install closed-source

Tags: debian, packaging

I'm writing an application that relies on a closed-source (but free-as-in-beer available) library.  I'm currently making a Debian repository to host it, and need a way to depend on that library, so I want to make a package that downloads the archive from a third party and installs it.  I'm not sure how to do the install such that it will uninstall nicely.  Any ideas for how to do this such that it integrates nicely into apt?

Comment: As long as you are allowed to distribute the free-as-in beer binaries, there is no problem - just put the binaries in the repository.  Debian already does this for some things in the non-free section.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to redistribute though (I don't think so).  However, anyone can download the binary from their own computer.  I think this is similar to what happens with adobe products...

Comment: In that case it sounds like a use case for the "installer-package" paradigm - like `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. You'll need to make a package whose install scripts fetch and install the non-free binaries in question (along with presenting the necessary click-wrap license agreement), and declare a dependency on that.

Comment: `flashplugin-nonfree` is another example of a package that does this.